# Getting the Top 5 Lowest Value in An array

Tags: java, arrays

I have a Java program that will output the top 5 lowest value from an array(disCent) with this kind of algorithm. This is my code:

```
   Arrays.sort(distCent);
  System.out.println(Arrays.asList(distCent));
```

Thanks for your recommendations on using sort. I've modified my code as above. Now, how do I check the position of the first 5 value in the sorted list from the original list so the output should be something like this:

```
Smallest is at x position with value of y.
2nd smallest is at x position with value of y....and so on.
```

Comment: Why not sort the array then just grab the first 5 indices?

Comment: I suggest you step through the code in your debugger to find the line which doesn't do what you expect.

Comment: @gonzo I need to keep track of the index(position) of the extracted lowest number

Comment: @gonzo Presumably the OP is looking for a more efficient solution than sorting, which is of complexity O(n log n).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the sort() method to get the values in ascending order then just grab the first five.

```
Arrays.sort( array );
```

If you need the position in the original array then get the index of the sorted array's first five values.

Answer (score 0):

As the other answer notes, you should use the `Arrays.sort` method. You really shouldn't re-invent the wheel for something this basic.

If, however, you cannot use the `Arrays` methods for some reason, and/or have a pathological hatred of sorting, the following code should do what you desire:

```
public static void lowest5(int[] args){
    int[][] ret = {{Integer.MAX_VALUE,0},{Integer.MAX_VALUE,0},{Integer.MAX_VALUE,0},{Integer.MAX_VALUE,0},{Integer.MAX_VALUE,0}}; \\There are much better ways to do this
    for(int i = 0; i < args.length;i++){
        int swapper = args[i]
        int swapper_index = i;
        for(int n = 0; n < 5;n++){
            if(swapper < ret[n][0]){
                swapper ^= ret[n][0]; \\this is a neat trick for swapping in place
                ret[n][0] ^= swapper; \\b ^ (a^b) = a
                swapper ^= ret[n][0]; \\ a ^ (a^b) = b

                swapper_index ^= ret[n][1];
                ret[n][1] ^= swapper_index;
                swapper_index ^= ret[n][1];
            }
        }
    }
    //print ret
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the lastest JDK installed it should be pretty easy:

```
    final int[] ints = {1, 3, 6, -10, 43, 100};
    final int[] just5 = Arrays.stream(ints).sorted().limit(5).toArray();
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(just5));
```

It works even with fewer than 5 items. (Arrays from java.util.Arrays)